# How do you pull out a specific set of characters from a giant mess?

Tags: objective-c, nsstring

I have a big string with a lot of different data and I need to grab one specific thing.  The string looks something like this;

Director: John Smith Writer: Jane Doe Producer: Harry Wilson ....

I need to grab just the directors name and none of the other info.  How do I grab just the info after the Director: and before Writer?

Answer (score 0):

IF the string will always have the word director before and writer after, find the location of substing director, sinf the location of the substring writer then take the characters between.

Comment: do I use componentsSeparatedByString?